# How To Add A User Alias Using Google Admin SDK Java API

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I am using the service account model and Google's Admin SDK Java API to retrieve and modify users.

The goal is to add an alias for an existing user.

```
Alias newAlias = new Alias();
newAlias.setId(userID);
newAlias.setAlias(alias);

Directory.Users.Aliases.Insert request = directory.users().aliases().insert(userID, newAlias);
request.execute();
```

execute() fails 100% of the time with the error message:

"Value set through a parameter is inconsistent with a value set in the request"

but of course does not identify the problem parameter or value, or provide a suggestion.

I tried all 8 combinations of scoped (or not scoped) userID and alias in newAlias, and userID in the request, with the same result.  By all 8 combinations, I mean:

```
newAlias.setId(userID);
newAlias.setAlias(alias);
insert(userID, newAlias);

newAlias.setId(userID@domain.com);
newAlias.setAlias(alias@domain.com);
insert(userID@domain.com, newAlias);
```

and so on...

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten aliases inserted using the following:

```
Alias alias = new Alias();
alias.setAlias(aliasString);
directory.users().aliases().insert(userId, alias).execute();
```

I don't have anything in the way of insight as to why your approach isn't working or why my approach works, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is worth adding that, while I believe the above approach is correct (using Directory.Aliases.Insert) and that I am missing some critical information or made a mistake, I also attempted to add the alias by updating the User object instead of Aliases, something like this:

```
List<String> aliases = new ArrayList<String>();
aliases.add(scopedAlias);  //userid@domain.com
User user = new User();
user = retrieveUser(uid);  //Gets current record from Google
user.setAliases(aliases);

Directory.Users.Update request
    = directory.users().update(uid, user);
request.execute();
```

That did not work either.

Anyone have an example of working code?

Answer (score 0):

S. McKinley's suggestion worked.

The key difference:

I had been including the call:

```
alias.setId(userId);
```

or

```
alias.setId(scopedUserId);  //userId@domain
```

Either one resulted in the "parameter is inconsistent with a value" error.  Leave it out and the alias gets created.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the customerId as follows

Go to admin.google.com
Security -> Set up single sign-on (SSO)
You will see URLs like this:

https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=Cxxxxxxxx

That Cxxxxxxxx is your customerId